sf error: OGR error: cannot export to WKT
I'm having issues running sf on my computer (R version 4.3.3, linux ubuntu 22.04.4). When trying to import a shapefile using st_read(), I am faced with the following error and warning messages:
> parks <- sf::st_read("Canada/PAs/ProtectedConservedArea_2023.gdb")

Multiple layers are present in data source /run/user/1472454/gvfs/smb-share:server=files.ok.ubc.ca,share=rsmarcus/GitHub/NDVI/Canada/PAs/ProtectedConservedArea.gdb, reading layer `ProtectedConservedArea'.
Use `st_layers' to list all layer names and their type in a data source.
Set the `layer' argument in `st_read' to read a particular layer.
Reading layer `ProtectedConservedArea' from data source 
  `/Canada/PAs/ProtectedConservedArea.gdb' using driver `OpenFileGDB'

Error: OGR error: cannot export to WKT
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  automatically selected the first layer in a data source containing more than one.
2: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Message 1: organizePolygons() received a polygon with more than 100 parts. The processing may be really slow.  You can skip the processing by setting METHOD=SKIP, or only make it analyze counter-clock wise parts by setting METHOD=ONLY_CCW if you can assume that the outline of holes is counter-clock wise defined
3: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: std::bad_alloc

I'm currently running sf version 1.0-16 (with GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, and PROJ 9.3.1) - these errors only appeared after updating my packages a little while ago. Before updating my packages, I was able to use all sf functions without issue, including importing this exact same shapefile. I have tried updating all my packages in case this was an issue with a dependency (using the update.packages() function), but this did not fix the issue.
I have attached a line of reproducible code using the shapefile of protected areas in Canada, which can be obtained here: https://data-donnees.az.ec.gc.ca/data/species/protectrestore/canadian-protected-conserved-areas-database/Databases
library('sf')
parks <- sf::st_read("Canada/PAs/ProtectedConservedArea_2023.gdb")

I'm hoping to fix this issue without having to resort to installing an older version of the package for my code to run!

Works for me with 1.0-16 which I've just updated to. My underlying library versions for sf are: "Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1". I get the same OGR warnings as you but not the WKT error. Its not something like you running out of disk space? Maybe there's some intermediate step where it has to write a load of WKT? Guessing now...

Hmm that error text only appears here https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/cfc321aa33633017274d6832589021417e21e700/src/gdal.cpp#L142 which makes me think its to do with coordinate reference processing. My system seems to manage, making a WKT crs based on Canada Albers EA Conic...

@Spacedman i don't believe it's related to disk space, as i'm running it on a machine with 500GB of RAM, so it shouldn't be an issue. i have GEOS 3.12.1, PROJ 9.3.1, and GDAL 3.8.4 as well, so sf should work with these

Ok, after many times re-installing sf, I was able to get it to work. I believe the issue was related to GDAL installation - I installed GDAL again using the steps here described, and after that I was able to succesfully load and use sf.
